# How to install network-manager without internet access?

Tags: 12.04, networking, indicator, network-manager

I have been trying to install some kind of network indicator to show my current bandwidth usage on the panel on top of the screen so I decided to install https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-network

But just after I have put 
`sudo apt-get install indicator-network` I have uninstalled a bunch of vital ubuntu applications e.g. network manager - which was my fault because Ubuntu warned me about it but hey! - why would it mark these applications to remove while installing just an indicator ?

Now I am unable to connect to the internet with that machine on Ubuntu. How can I install network manager back or install it from the USB boot drive with 12.04 that I have ?

Comment: Since you were able to post a question here, means you're online. In that case, go to this [site](http://ubottu.com/ljl/apt/?repo=Precise&arch=i386&package=network-manager&have=ubuntu-desktop) and download the precise network-manager package with dependencies and then install it by running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` from the terminal.

Comment: This is duplicate question :)

Comment: @msPeachy I am not online - I posted this question from another machine.

Comment: Then do it on that machine, the one you are using right now. Also, see [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-display-network-upload-download.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need NetworkManager to connect to a network. Assuming you're using automatic configuration (probably you are) you just need to `sudo dhclient eth0` to get an IP address (replace eth0 with your network device if that's the case).

Comment: Thanks for that - the problem for me was that I tried to do it on wireless interface `wlan0` and it was impossible ( I still do not know how to do it :/ )

Comment: via ifconfig came to know that my eth0 is lo. sudo dhclient lo works fine but internet still not working. Any additional setting required.

Comment: @SidraSultana `lo` is the [loopback](http://askubuntu.com/q/247625/65926) interface. If `ifconfig` show only the loopback, the other interfaces are probably "down". Run `ifconfig -a` to list all the interfaces; if you see an `eth0`, run `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` then `sudo dhclient eth0`.

Comment: thank you so mush for your answer! I am very tired of trying to find how to make my eth work after debian installation!

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Will fail. Note what dependencies are needed to install the package.
Mine were-

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iputils-arping libnl-route-3-200 modemmanager network-manager network-manager-gnome usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data wpasupplicant
```

The download will fail obviously with error:

```
Failed to fetch
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.3-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

Download all such links which gives above error including network-manager by some other system. I downloaded the following links-

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.3-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wpasupplicant/wpasupplicant_0.7.3-6ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iputils/iputils-arping_20101006-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20120120-0ubuntu1_all.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch/usb-modeswitch_1.2.3+repack0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/modemmanager/modemmanager_0.5.2.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-applet/network-manager-gnome_0.9.4.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb
```

The links above does not contain the link of network-manager itself. You can download it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/network-manager); from a software mirror close to you. Take care to choose the appropriate architecture (amd64 for 64-bit, i386 for 32-bit), and release version of your installed OS.

Now copy the deb files to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Run `sudo-apt-get install network-manager` in terminal.
Now it will pick up deb files from cache and will not prompt to download them.
If all goes well network-manager will be installed.

Finally reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I managed to connect to wireless like this for WPA APs

```
wpa_passphrase networkname password > foo.conf
killall -9 wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -i wlan0 -c foo.conf
```

If you're using WEP then than you can do it with

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid network
iwconfig wlan0 key password
```